# A strange result in python using function multiprocessing.Pool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-3.6

Here is code:

one:

```
import multiprocessing
import datetime
import time
a = [i for i in range(100)]
res1 = []
def jia(a,b,c):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return a + b + c
res1_time_start = datetime.datetime.now()
p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
res1 = [p.apply_async(jia,(i,1,1)) for i in a]
res1 = [i.get() for i in res1]
res1_time_end = datetime.datetime.now()
print((res1_time_end - res1_time_start).seconds)
```

the other:

```
import multiprocessing
import datetime
import time
a = [i for i in range(100)]
res1 = []
def jia(a,b,c):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return a + b + c
res1_time_start = datetime.datetime.now()
p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
for i in a:
    res1.append(p.apply_async(jia,(i,1,1)).get())
res1_time_end = datetime.datetime.now()
print((res1_time_end - res1_time_start).seconds)
```

The strange result is that the former cost 2.5s but the latter cost 10s.
Why?Does list.append Blocks process?

Comment: At first glance, `get` is a blocking method.

Comment: `p.apply_async(..).get()` is a blocking op.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `append()` doesn't block, but `.get()` does.  It's the *purpose* of `.get()` to block.  In

```
res1 = [p.apply_async(jia,(i,1,1)) for i in a]
res1 = [i.get() for i in res1]
```

*all* the work is given to the pool by the first line before *any* `.get()` is invoked by the second line.  But in

```
for i in a:
    res1.append(p.apply_async(jia,(i,1,1)).get())
```

the `.get()` waits for a single piece of work to finish before it allows the loop to continue to even start the next piece of work.  You've serialized the work - nothing useful happens in parallel.